# Projectile and magit branch checkout

Tags: magit, projectile

Every time I use `M-x magit-status b b` to checkout a different branch, the projectile cache is of course out of date. I then use `M-x projectile-invalidate-cache` to force projectile to rebuild its cache and that does work fine.

How could I automate this? I have no idea how to check which `magit-xyz` command is triggered when using <kbd>b b</kbd> in `magit-status`. And even if I knew: How would I transparently "overwrite" that command to first call its previous definition and then `projectile-invalidate-cache`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have no idea how to check which magit-xyz command is triggered when using `b b` in `magit-status`.

Use <kbd>b ? b</kbd> in `magit-status`.  This tells you it runs `magit-checkout`.

> And even if I knew: How would I transparently "overwrite" that command to first call its previous definition and then `projectile-invalidate-cache`?

Use advice:

```el
(defun run-projectile-invalidate-cache (&rest _args)
  ;; We ignore the args to `magit-checkout'.
  (projectile-invalidate-cache nil))
(advice-add 'magit-checkout
            :after #'run-projectile-invalidate-cache)
(advice-add 'magit-branch-and-checkout ; This is `b c'.
            :after #'run-projectile-invalidate-cache)
```

---

Another idea might be to use file notifications to invalidate the cache (this could work also if you did a checkout from the command line).

Comment: This results in `run-projectile-invalidate-cache: Wrong number of arguments: ((t) (arg) "Remove the current project's files from `projectile-projects-cache'.`. Any ideas?

Comment: @NickolayKolev oops, `projectile-invalidate-cache` requires an argument, fixed now.